# Concept of RecordReaders

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, recordreader

We know that prior to Mapper phase the files are split and the RecordReader starts working to emit a  input to the Mapper. My question is whether the reducer uses a RecordReader class to read the data emitted by the mapper?

---

because reducer takes input too!!
Please Explain!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview of the mapreduce steps is as follows

```
1) InputFormat :

 - Validates the Input.

 - Splits the input files.        

 - Gives Record Reader Implementation to give input to Mapper.

2)Mapper Phase

3)Shuffle and Sort Phase

4)Reducer Phase

5) OutputFormat     

 - Validates the Output Specification.  

 - Provides Record Writer Implementation used to write the output files.
```

Reducer does not use record reader...

Comment: Thankyou for adding more confidence to my concepts. Actually I was stuck up in a Custom File Format Program which made me ask this. 
Thank You!!